# how to query in ravendb studio?

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I have no problem querying RavenDB from code, but sometimes a quick lookup directly to RavenDB would be nice. Unfortunately, I cannot figure it out despite tips that it uses Lucene syntax.

For example, I have a `RegionLocation` document:

```
{
  "RegionId": 804291854,
  "Name": "Miami",
  "Description": null,
  "DbRowStatus": 0,
  "CreatedBy": "Zorro",
  "UpdatedBy": null,
  "DeletedBy": null,
  "CreatedOn": "2013-06-05T18:31:37.4332753",
}
```

I haven't had any luck with quering it. `RegionLocation.Name: M*` returns no results.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you already have an index that has the name mapped, or you are building a new dynamic index against the `RegionLocation` documents, then the syntax for your query would just be:

```
Name: M*
```

I agree that the documentation could be better - especially the in-application help.  But you can find most of what you need to know [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/studio/indexes).

**UPDATE**

This was raised as [Issue #1250](http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-1250), and closed in RavenDB 2.5.2750.  The studio now includes easily accessible help:

[image: Screenshot]

The popup shows when you hover over the (i) icon, and the "Query syntax online" link points at the relevant [Lucene documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html).

Comment: thanks, it works without Document name, weird because when I change Index source from the menu it is automatically added to .Name...BTW why it has to be index there? In SQL server I can query all fields whether are indexed or not.

Comment: Matt I have to disagree, I mean your solution works but the documentation lacks and lacks a lot. There is not explanation of what kind of Syntax studio is able to accept and the intellisense give you the wrong "impression" when building a query. Far away from being a complete product IMHO

Comment: @Raffaeu - Not sure why you think this one bit of contextual help would make or break it being a "complete product", but as you can see by my updated answer - this was already addressed last October.

Comment: @MattJohnson it does in the moment that the product is not using a standard query language like T-SQL or LinQ and it forces you to "guess" the syntax. Look at LinqPad, that's a complete query editor

Comment: @Raffaeu - It uses Lucene syntax.  You might not be as familiar with that as TSQL or LINQ, but that's because it serves a different purpose.  It *does* provide Intellisense, if that's what you're looking for.  If you think it should be something more, perhaps consider contributing to the [new HTML-based studio for Raven3](https://github.com/JudahGabriel/ravendb/tree/Raven.Studio.Html5/Raven.Studio.Html5).  But this is getting off topic for StackOverflow...

Comment: @MattJohnson I was able to speak with Ayende and get a clear explanation of what is RavenDB and how it is supposed to be used. For ETL and Reporting I have been suggested to replicate the data over SQL Server and build my Cubes/Reports using a RDBMS instead of RavenDB.